# Same CSS producing different font sizes on different pages

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to create CSS for a small-screen view of my web application, and I'm running into maddening font-size issues. Here's the scenario.

I have a class, lets call it .noListItemsWords.

```
.noListItemsWords {
   font-size: 80%;
}
```

The only parent anywhere up the DOM from this on both pages that sets the font-size is body, which has a font-size of 24pt.

On page one, the browser is rendering this element with a font-size of 47.7681px:
[image: browser rendering of the element on page 1]

On page two, the browser is only rendering this at font-size of 32px:
[image: browser rendering of the element on page 2]

Why does this happen? Is there any way to deal with it?

EDIT:
Showing that using a base percentage on my body tag and rem units for my font does not fix the issue:

[image: page one using rem]
[image: page two using rem]

Tested in Google Chrome 57

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I don't really understand the reason why this fixes it, but adding a meta tag for the viewport made the font behavior go back to expected:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set the `font-size` as a percentage in your `body` CSS. Then use `rem` to set the size of individual strings of text.

`rem` will scale the font in proportion to the percentage that you put in your base `body` class.

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
}

.noListItemsWord {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

Comment: If I did that, what is font size in the body a percentage OF?
It made sense to me to put an absolute font size at the body, and use a relative size (percentage) everywhere else. That also doesn't answer the question of why the way I have written it is NOT working

Comment: It's your base percentage for the whole website. So in the future if you have to scale all text and spacing up or down you can just change the percentage value in the body without having to change every `px` or whatever value individually. So you should use `rem` to space your divs and everything out.

Comment: That still doesn't answer why to use a relative unit at my base element, or why my scenario as-written doesn't work. I've looked up rem independently and see that it is relative to your base element which is definitely more deterministic sounding than percent or em, but still looking for more answers on the other point

Comment: When you don't have a base percentage set the browsers will render the percentage value differently.

Comment: I have updated the original post, using a base percentage and rem units does not fix the issue. The browser still renders the font on two different pages with two different sizes

Comment: Hmm that is strange, what browsers are you using?