# Why are these pages with identical style tags producing different font-sizes?

Tags: php, html, css

I have two nearly identical web pages. In fact, I copied the code for the first and saved it as the 2nd before just modifying some of the elements in the 2nd. The styles in the style tag were left exactly the same. They are displaying different font-sizes, and I haven't the foggiest idea why.

Without getting off on tangents about what I should be doing (e.g. using a stylesheet) or nitpicking my code (unless it actually answers the question), **can someone please explain why I'm getting two different styles using identical style tags?**

P.S. - I know I can fiddle and get them both to have the same style, but it drives me crazy not knowing why this is happening. Believe me, I would have already had them looking the same by now if it weren't for my obsessive desire to understand things I don't understand.

P.S.S. - Adding a meta tag for the viewport, as suggested in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545565/same-css-producing-different-font-sizes-on-different-pages), did not work for me.

**---DETAILS---**

**options.php**, the desired style, looks like this in mobile Chrome on an LG phone...the screenshots below are from Opera (Chrome) DevTools with device toolbar toggled on with Galaxy S5 being emulated. (These screenshots are exactly what I am seeing on my real device, the LG phone):
[image: First desired page]

**admin.php**, has noticeably smaller font-sizes. It's hard to see in these screenshots, but the img at the top stays exactly the same size. Also, notice that both screenshots are the same width:
[image: 2nd undesired page]

Code for **options.php** (php renders it):

```
$admin_str = "<div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"admin.php\">Admin Options</a></div>";

$body = "
    <div id=\"hero-img\">
       <img src=\"imgs/logo.png\">
    </div>
    <h1>Hi $esc_fName!</h1>
    <h2 id=\"subheading\">What would you like to do next?</h2>
    <div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"abcde.php\">Record------</a></div>
    <div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"fghij.php\">Manage -----</a></div>
    <div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"manage.php\">Manage my account information</a></div>
    <div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"klmnop.php\">Add a ----</a></div>
    $admin_str
    <div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"logout.php\">Log out</a></div>
        ";
    echo <<<_END
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>------- Options</title>
                <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                <style>
                    body {                                  
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 100%;
                    }
                    #main-content {
                        width: 75%;
                        margin: 40px auto;
                    }
                    #hero-img {
                        width: 50%;
                        margin: 50px auto;
                    }
                    #subheading {
                        margin-bottom: 50px;
                    }
                    .a-div {
                        display: block;
                        margin-top: 20px;
                    }
                    a {
                        font-size: 21pt;
                        color: #000055;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
                    a:hover {
                        color: blue;
                    }
                    a:active {
                        background-color: #333333;
                        color: #E70B81;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="main-content">
                    $body
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
_END;
```

Code for **admin.php** (php also renders it):

```
$body = "
    <div id=\"hero-img\">
        <img src=\"imgs/dtlogo.png\">
    </div>
    <h1>Hi $esc_fName!</h1>
    <h2 id=\"subheading\">Administrative Options</h2>
    <div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"appremails.php\">Add a new approved email</a></div>
    <div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"options.php\">Back to main options</a></div>
    <div class=\"a-div\"><a href=\"logout.php\">Log out</a></div>
    ";

    echo <<<_END
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>Administrative Options</title>
                <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                <style>
                    body {                                  
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 100%;
                    }
                    #main-content {
                        width: 75%;
                        margin: 40px auto;
                    }
                    #hero-img {
                        width: 50%;
                        margin: 50px auto;
                    }
                    #subheading {
                        margin-bottom: 50px;
                    }
                    .a-div {
                        display: block;
                        margin-top: 20px;
                    }
                    a {
                        font-size: 21pt;
                        color: #000055;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
                    a:hover {
                        color: blue;
                    }
                    a:active {
                        background-color: #333333;
                        color: #E70B81;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="main-content">
                    $body
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
_END;
```

**UPDATE** --Per the request by Donkey Shame, here are the computed font-sizes:

```
_______________________________
|______|  1st pg.  |  2nd pg.  |
|______|___________|___________|
|  h1  |  40.133px |   32px    |
|______|___________|___________|
|  h2  |  36.133px |   24px    |
|______|___________|___________|
|  a   |  38.133px |   28px    |
|______|___________|___________|
```

**UPDATE #2** --As Dejan suggested, I tried viewing the two sites in desktop mode, and they are the same even when they are not the same when viewed on mobile.

**UPDATE #3** --After some tinkering, I got the two pages to have the same style when viewed on mobile. Of course, I never doubted I'd do that, and it still doesn't answer my original question regarding the original code, but it actually might have helped me to narrow it down to a very specific culprit. Here's what I did. I removed the `font-size` altogether from `body`. Then I changed the `h1` and `h2` both to `div`s. I edited the style tag to reflect those new `div`s. Then I set `font-size: 5vw` for the `#heading div` (the old `h1`). I set `font-size: 3.022727vw` (more on that 3.022727 later) for the `#subheading div` (the old `h2`). I set `font-size: 3.5vw` for the `a` elements. **Here's where it gets strange again:** If I change the 3.022727vw to 3.022726vw in both style tags, the   1st page has virtually no change (which is what should be expected), but the 2nd page does this (note how the `#subheading` changes the font-size of the `a` tags also):

**admin.php** - `#subheading { font-size: 3.022727vw; }`
[image: page2-3.022727vw]

**admin.php** - `#subheading { font-size: 3.022726vw; }`
[image: page2-3.022726vw]

Comment: What does `$admin_str` contain?

Comment: @kerbholz I just edited the question with the info you requested

Comment: How does the size look in desktop view when trying in chrome, safari (if avaliable), opera and firefox?

Comment: What a head scratcher. Can you view the computed styles for font size in the dev tools and report back what difference there is, if any, between the two pages?

Comment: I'll add that I just copied the style tags from these two pages and wrote a quick php program to test the equality, and they are identically (===) equal. Just FYI.

Comment: And both pages reside on the same server? And screenshots were taken with the same browser/settings? Have you checked the pages in a different browser (without extensions maybe)? Cleared browser cache?

Comment: Does the setting of `width` & `height` of `html` and `body` to `100%` solve this?

Comment: Just wanted to warn you from such code generation. Please forget it as a nightmare and never use again.

Comment: @DonkeyShame I just updated the question with the requested info

Comment: @Enzy no, setting the width/height in html, body does not resolve the issue

Comment: @kerbholz both pages do reside on the same server. both images taken with same browser and settings. Haven't yet checked the results in different browsers. Working on that.

Comment: @Dejan.S I think you're on to something. I've tried only opera for now, but both pages have identical styles in desktop view. It's only when moving to mobile that they screw up. (And, if not obvious, I intend mobile to be the main use case)

Comment: Hmm. Not that it solves your mystery, but page 2 appears to be rendering correctly. Could it have something to do with how `pt` gets rendered at various `dpi` settings?

Comment: @DonkeyShame I'm sure that `pt` is terrible to use, but I'm not sure why that would be the culprit. I'm viewing both pages under identical circumstances. Also, since posting the question, I've tried changing all of the font-sizes to `em` sizes, and I'm still getting the discrepancy between the two pages.

Comment: Fair enough. Typically, I suppose, one would use `pt` for print CSS rather than screen, but (as you wrote) you've tried other units and the discrepancy remains. Any chance we could view the problems pages? 

If you're devving locally, maybe you could throw it up on `serveo.net` (depending on your comfort level with exposing your local server). I trust Trevor's work there, but you may not... At least that way, we could examine the offending code.

Comment: @DonkeyShame I appreciate your offer to view the actual pages to try to determine the issue. Unfortunately, both of these pages require privileges that I can't grant.

Comment: Please post here when you figure it out. I'm very interested now. :)

Comment: In that case it can be related to emulator, I'm thinking the pixel density, I would try this on a real device before spending any more time on it.

Comment: @Dejan.S I've been testing it on a real device this whole time. It's just that the screenshots were from the emulator. But I've also been testing it on an LG phone from the beginning. I guess that was not clear. I apologize. The results from the emulator have been replicated exactly in the LG phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a user-agent scaling issue. The solution to avoid such problems is to add [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) inside the `<head>` section ([is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14775195)):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Without viewport tag:

[image: Admin page without viewport meta tag]

Both pages with viewport tag:

[image: Admin page]
[image: Options page]

Comment: I tried this before I posted my initial question (as you can see in the wording of my question). It caused even more unpredictability, so I assumed it was not working. Now, however, it appears to have completely fixed the issue. However, you still have not answered my question...WHY was I getting two different styles using identical style tags when viewing on exactly the same devices? If you'll please answer that, I'll choose this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @snoski I been away from CSS and mobiles for sometime, but adding the viewport meta is usually the first thing the css+mobile tutorials teach you to do. Without it, the browsers will try to "fit" the page on the screen by zooming out.

Comment: I apologize for being a stick in the mud here. I do greatly appreciate the info you've provided. I have read it all, and I am now convinced that this tag is important. However, I still do not understand why two virtually identical pages with identical style tags served by the same server were rendered differently in the same browser on the same device. I don't understand how the lack of this tag (when neither page had the tag) should have resulted in two different renders.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in applying body font-size as 100%. There're two ways of solving the issue: replace `font-size: 100%;` with `font-size: 1rem;` or with `font-size: 16px;` Bootstrap for example uses `font-size: 1rem;`.

If it doesn't help open Devtools of your browser, open a page with smaller font-size and inspect font sizes of  and texts. It might be overwritten by some additional styles.

```
<style>
  body {                                  
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
```

Comment: I've always thought that `body { font-size: 100%; }` was really bizarre, but I read somewhere that it was good practice. *shrug* I dunno. Regardless, I tried `font-size: 1rem`, and it unfortunately did not fix the problem.

Comment: And what about `font-size: 16 px;` ?

Comment: The browser does know. It will take whatever is in its settings. If you use `font-size: 16px;` the user can't set a higher font-size if wanted, that is bad practice. `font-size: 100%;` will set to default 16px. You can do `font-size: 1rem;` and it will become whatever the "root" is, that is the browser setting. @snoski